# How to use XBox360 DPad so it registers only one direction?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

I've bought XBox360 controller recently and don't quite understand DPad.

A problem is that when I press DPad not firmly (push only have a way in) it doesn't register the press, and when I press it firmly, for example down, sometimes it registers as both: "press down" and "press right".
Is there a technique - how I should press DPad? Or maybe a software, which prevents two presses to be registered in too short period of time?

P.S. I'm have this problem on PC, in Dark Souls 1 and 2 at the moment.

Comment: I would imagine your controller is faulty, that's what your description leads me to believe. Are you playing Dark Souls on a PC with the 360 controller, or on an Xbox 360?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf on PC.

Comment: That could also be an issue. Have you installed the proper drivers for the 360 controller?

Comment: In my experience, this is just how bad the d-pad on the official 360 controller has always been. I've always had issues like this on any official 360 pad I've ever owned or used. It's always been a real mind bender to me how the design even got approved.

Comment: The D-pad on the 360 controllers were never the greatest.  They were decent, but overtime they definitely wore a lot and dirt would easily clog it up from being pressed properly.  Is the controller new or used?  If used, its possible some dirt is lodged under the D-pad.  I recommend (if you have the ability to) try out a different 360 controller with your PC and see what happens.  Perhaps one from a friend you could borrow.  If it still seems off, then it could be the PC, otherwise it likely just the other controller.